# SELECT SQL COM WHERE "DUPLO"

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Estou tentando fazer uma consulta no Banco de dados MySQL com a seguinte sintaxe

```
SELECT id, codigo, faca, descricao, vendedor, imagem 
FROM produtos
WHERE sit = 1
  AND descricao = ESTE
```

Até essa parte ele funciona perfeitamente : `SELECT id, codigo, faca, descricao, vendedor, imagem FROM produtos WHERE sit = 1`

Porém a consulta apresenta o seguinte erro quando coloco a ultima parte do código :  `#1054 - Coluna 'ESTE' desconhecida em 'where clause'`

Comment: **ESTE** não aparentemente deve vir entre aspas simples, assim `and descricao = 'ESTE'`, está assim?

Answer (score 2):

O erro é exatamente o que [Ricardo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/57220/ricardo-pontual) apontou em um comentário; como está no `select`, `ESTE` está com sintaxe de uma coluna da tabela `produtos`, e tal coluna não existe (é o que diz o erro).

Aparentemente você comparar se a coluna `descricao` tem *ESTE* como valor, então a consulta ficaria assim:

```
SELECT id, codigo, faca, descricao, vendedor, imagem 
FROM produtos
WHERE sit = 1
  AND descricao = 'ESTE'
```